# rails find created_on withing last 5 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
@gameRequests = GameRequest.find(:first, :conditions => ["created_on >= ?", created_on])
```

I'd like to find the oldest record within the last 5 minutes. How can I subtract the 5 minutes from created_on to do this? I cant seem to find any examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want is:

```
@gameRequest = GameRequest.first(:conditions => ["created_on >= ?", DateTime.now - 5.minutes])
```

BTW, are you sure the field is named **created_on** and not **created_at**? Also, **.first** gets only the first record, not all of them. For that, you need **.all**

Comment: Yep, should have been created_at. Works a charm, thanks Srdjan.

Comment: Or else, `5.minutes.ago`. More elegant!

Answer (score 1):

```
gameRequests = GameRequest.find(:first, :conditions => ["created_on >= ?", created_on - 5.minute])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply fl00r, answer was useful but not exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`@gameRequests = GameRequest.find(:first, :conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Time.now - 5.minutes], :order => "created_at ASC")`